# How to dismiss multiple ViewController instead of initial ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have this case

- `LoginViewController - initial ViewController`) present `NavigationControllerB` (in NavigationControllerB I have many ViewController)
- `NavigationControllerB` present `ViewControllerC`
- `ViewControllerC` present `ViewControllerD`

In the `ViewControllerD`, when the login section is expired, I will move back to `LoginViewController` so I want to dismiss all ViewControlelr instead of `LoginViewController`?

Any idea to do that?
Any help or suggestion would be great appreciated

I have tried like that: When I dismiss the `ViewControllerD` successful, I send a block to `ViewControllerC` then I continue dismiss the `ViewControllerC`.
After that I will dismiss the `NavigationControllerB`, but `NavigationControllerB` have many `ViewController` so I need to write many `block code` so I don't think it's a good idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If LoginViewController is your initialViewController, you can use this code :

```
//dismiss all presented view controllers if any
            UIViewController *vc = self.presentingViewController;
            while (vc.presentingViewController) {
                vc = vc.presentingViewController;
            }
            [vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Comment: @PhanVănLinh - Great!! Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like,

```
 [[[[[self parentViewController]parentViewController] parentViewController]parentViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

   // perform task after completion
}];
```

Make sure that number of parent viewcontroller. this is example dissmiss paraentview controller according to your scenario.

**Update :**

try something like this,

```
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

    [[[[[self parentViewController]parentViewController] parentViewController]parentViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

        // perform task after completion
    }];

}];
```

**Update 2 :**

```
    [[[[[self parentViewController]parentViewController] parentViewController]parentViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}];
```

can do something like this, dismiss all parent vc and then dismiss current vc
Hope this will help :)

Comment: I tried it in `ViewControllerD`. but the `ViewControllerD` don't dismiss. Here is my code `[[[self parentViewController] parentViewController ]dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`
And I'm sure this code get called

Comment: first need to  dismiss present vc and then all parent. check my update in answer

Comment: I use your update code. And it only dismiss only `ViewControllerD`

Comment: solution 2 not working :D. `ViewControllerD` don't dismiss